# python : Where did the file go?

Tags: python

I am calling a python script from a rails controller. Say the location of the controller is `x` and location of the python script is `y`. The python script is such that it create a file to write `x=open("file","w")`. The script executes fine. But after the execution, I'm not able to find the write file. Its neither in location `x` nor location `y`. I also used the command `locate file` to find the file, but the command gives no output.

Where should the file ideally go? And why I'm not able to find it

Comment: If you are able to view the script's output, perhaps `import os; print os.getcwd()` will give you a hint.

Comment: Don't edit your question to add a new one. Ask it separately (or better still, search for existing questions that ask the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that might depend on what your webserver has as a working directory.

locate only finds stuff in it's database, so it won't instantly know of new files. Try

```
find / -name file
```

Comment: This will probably take a while. ;)

Comment: Sure will, but should eventually find the answer (and prepended with sudo or otherwise run with root permissions definitely will)

Comment: @Carsten: It did. But I found it. \m/. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLandau: Is there a way I can set the location of file as `y`?

Comment: @nish, yes look for documentation on os.path

Comment: @nish Just slap the directory in front of it, i.e. `/path/to/whereever/your/path/y/is/file`.